# Can a conductor act as a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, conductors, batteries

If a conductor is kept in an external electric field then it develops charge separation and counters the external field. If we connect its opposite ends using a wire and a load then can it act as a battery.
[image]
Is the above argument correct?
I am confused because I have studied that we use non electrostatic agents to create charge separation in a battery while in the above case we are using electrostatic agent.

Comment: What will be the effect of the electric field on the wire?

Comment: Didn't mention it in the post but I was already confused about it sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you remove the external field before you attach the wires, then the charges will redistribute themselves within the conductor (the "bar" in your figure) and when you attach the wire everything will already be in a neutral, static state.

If you attach the wire in the presence of the external field then it will be equally affected by the field both in the presence of the field and when the field is removed.  All you've done here is made your conducting piece bigger.  This also will not keep a persistent separation to drive a circuit.  To the extent that charges flow through your wire, it is due to the external field not due to a any stored potential energy ("battery") in the bar.

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that in the presence of an external field it will act as a conductor with a cavity.Am I correct sir?